# How to solve TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto' in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.2.1.0

I have task that collects information over items, and I setup a register for the task. For example, I use jq to parse a JSON file,

```
hello.json
----------
{
    "name" : "hello file",
    "english" : "hello",
    "spanish" : "hola",
    "german" : "wie gehts"
}

- name: parse the hello.json file
  shell: |
      jq -r '.{{ item }}' < hello.json
  register: hellos
  with_items:
  - english
  - spanish
  - german

- debug: var=hellos
```

The debug shows

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hellos": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                # snipped
                "item": "english", 
                "stdout" : "hello",
                # snipped
           },
            {
                # snipped
                "item": "spanish", 
                "stdout" : "hola",
                # snipped
           },
           {
                # snipped
                "item": "german", 
                "stdout" : "wie gehts",
                # snipped
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now if I want to get the stdout value of the hellos register, I tried this

```
- name: Display hello messages
  debug: msg="{{ hellos.results | selectattr("item","equalto",item) | map(attribute="stdout") | first }} worlld"
  with_items:
  - english
  - spanish
  - german
```

I get

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

I'm basically parsing the hellos register for the "item" and getting its "stdout" attribute i the second debug task. Where's my error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do some really strange stuff here. I'm sure your original task can be solved much easier.

But to answer your question "*Why `equalto` filter not found?*": update Jinja2.

Check with `pip list | grep Jinja2`.
`equalto` is introduced in ver. 2.8.

Comment: Yep it was Jinja2 v2.7.2. Upgrading to 2.8.x fixed the solution.

Comment: how to upgrade to Jinja2 2.8 ?

Comment: Jinja neglects to [include this in its changelog](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#eq)

Comment: And then, what must we do?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible in version 2.3 and less has no test named `equalto`, so you can create one custom test plugin name `equal_to`.  Simply create one file in the test_plugins directory.

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
# vi ./test_plugins/anything.py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

def equal_to(value, other):
  return value == other

class TestModule(object):
    def tests(self):
        return {
         'equal_to': equal_to
       }
```

Happy developments...