# Error was a <class 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError'>, original message: no test named 'equalto'"} while running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible-template

## Ansible Playbook:

---

- name: VMware VM Inventory Generator
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
  hostname: xxxxxxxxxxx
  username: administrator@vsphere.local
  password: xxxxxxxxxxx
  export_type: html # choices['html', 'csv']
  tasks:

  - name: Gather fact for all vm
    vmware_vm_facts:
    hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    register: vms
  - name: Gather facts for vm summary
    vmware_guest_facts:
    hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    datacenter: DC
    name: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
    register: gather_facts_for_vm_summary_result
    loop: "{{ vms.virtual_machines }}"
    loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
  - name: Gather facts for vm each properties
    vmware_guest_facts:
    hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    datacenter: DC
    name: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
    - alarmActionsEnabled
    - overallStatus
    - config.name
    - config.annotation
    - config.flags
    - config.managedBy
    - guest.hostName
    - guest.net
    - summary.storage
    - summary.quickStats
    - summary.config
    - summary.runtime
    - config.memoryAllocation
    register: gather_facts_for_vm_each_properties
    loop: "{{ vms.virtual_machines }}"
    loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
  - name: Set of combine data
    set_fact:
    data: >-
    {{ data | default([])
    + [item.instance | combine(combine_data.instance)]
    }}
    vars:
    combine_data: >-
    {{ gather_facts_for_vm_each_properties.results
    | selectattr('instance.config.name','equalto',item['instance']['hw_name'])
    | list
    | first
    }}
    loop: "{{ gather_facts_for_vm_summary_result.results }}"
    loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.instance.hw_name }}"
  - name: Generate VM inventory report(html)
    template:
    src: report_html.j2
    dest: vcenter_inventory.html
    when: export_type == "html"
  - name: Generate VM inventory report(csv)
    template:
    src: report_csv.j2
    dest: vcenter_inventory.csv
    when: export_type == "csv"

## =====
[root@junosansible vmware]# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.10
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]

[root@junosansible vmware]# pip3 list | grep Jinja2

Jinja2                             3.0.1

## Error:-

TASK [Set of combine data] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ gather_facts_for_vm_each_properties.results\n  | selectattr('instance.config.name','equalto',item['instance']['hw_name'])\n  | list\n  | first\n}}'. Error was a <class 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError'>, original message: no test named 'equalto'"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here: [How to solve TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto' in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660161/how-to-solve-templateruntimeerror-no-test-named-equalto-in-ansible).

Check your Jinja pip version (pip list | grep Jinja2) - it needs to be at least 2.8.